# Could set selected value in drop down dynamically using php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I need to select value dynamically using PHP in drop down list but in my case its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
    $citySelected = "";
    if(!isset($_GET['city'])){
        $citySelected = 'selected="selected"';
    }
?>
<select id="selectedLoc" name="selectedLoc" class="chosen-select form-control">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="0" <?php echo $citySelected; ?>>Global</option>
    <?php 
        foreach ($locationArr as $key => $value) {

            $id = $value['id'];
            $city = $value['city'];
            $location = $value['location'];

            $selected = "";
            if(isset($_GET['city']) &&  $_GET['city']== $value['id']) {
                $selected ='selected="selected"';
            }
            echo "<option value='$id' $selected>$location</option>";

        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Here I need when there is any `query string` value then it will match with respective `id` and select that option and if there is no query string value at all then the `global` option will select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside if condition ';' is missing. It should be like

```
if(isset($_GET['city']) &&  $_GET['city']== $value['id']){echo ' selected="selected"';}else{echo '';}
```

You can also use conditional operator for code simplicity, eg:-

```
<?php echo (isset($_GET['city']) &&  $_GET['city']== $value['id'])? ' selected="selected"':''; ?>
```